# Chromecast with multiple activity

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm developing an application supporting both Chromecast and ActionbarSherlock.
In every activity, I create a MediaRouteButton in the ActionBar.

My problem is, I didn't connect to the Chromecast device in the first Activity, and go to the second Activity. In the second one, I connect to the Chromecast device. It runned into the `onRouteSelected()` of the second Activity, then runned into `onDeviceAvailable()` -> `openSession()` of the first Activity.
I don't know why it didn't run into `onDeviceAvailable()` on the second Activity.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Here is my code in both activities:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cast_sample);

    mMetaData = new ContentMetadata();    


    mMediaSelectionDialog = new MediaSelectionDialog(this);
    mCastContext = new CastContext( getApplicationContext());
    MediaRouteHelper.registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider( mCastContext, this );
    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance( getApplicationContext() );
    mMediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteHelper.buildMediaRouteSelector( MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_CAST );
    mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
}
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cast_sample, menu);
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) mediaRouteMenuItem.getActionView();
        mMediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector( mMediaRouteSelector );
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);       
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
        super.onStop();        
    }

  private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
            MediaRouteHelper.requestCastDeviceForRoute(route);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
            try {
                if (mSession != null) {
                    logVIfEnabled(TAG, "Ending session and stopping application");
                    mSession.setStopApplicationWhenEnding(true);
                    mSession.endSession();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onRouteUnselected: mSession is null");
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onRouteUnselected:");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onRouteUnselected:");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMessageStream = null;
            mSelectedDevice = null;
        }
    }


  @Override
  public void onDeviceAvailable(CastDevice device, String myString,
        MediaRouteStateChangeListener listener) {
        mSelectedDevice = device;
        logVIfEnabled(TAG, "Available device found: " + myString);
        openSession();
  }
  private void openSession() {
        mSession = new ApplicationSession(mCastContext, mSelectedDevice);
        .....
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a separate ChromecastAdapter Singleton class that implements MediaRouteAdapter.  I call registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider on creation and never unregister it.  The ChromecastAdapter contains all the Chromecast state.  All I have to do in each activity is pass in my MediaRouteButton and call setRouteSelector on it.

```
public class ChromeCastAdapter implements MediaRouteAdapter { 

    ...
    private static ChromeCastAdapter instance = null;

    public static ChromeCastAdapter getInstance(Context activity) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ChromeCastAdapter(activity);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ChromeCastAdapter(Context activity) {
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();

        castContext = new CastContext(context);
        mediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(context);

        MediaRouteHelper.registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider(castContext, this);

        mediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteHelper.buildMediaRouteSelector(MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_CAST);

        mediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouterCallback();
        mediaRouter.addCallback(mediaRouteSelector, mediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
    }

    public void setMediaRouteButtonSelector(MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton) {
        mediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(mediaRouteSelector);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: is this still valid? Looks promising and the only resource about this topic I found so far.

Comment: I was working with the private SDK at the time.  I haven't evaluated the public SDK that was released in February 2014, but I wouldn't be surprised if Google has made this easier.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue here:
`MediaRouteHelper.registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider( mCastContext, this );` will return false in the second Activity. Because I already registered it in the first Activity.

I just think a temporary solution that:

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        MediaRouteHelper.registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider( mCastContext, this );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        MediaRouteHelper.unregisterMediaRouteProvider(mCastContext);
    }
```

But When I unregister, I have to connect to the Chromecast device again. Because It'll release all the state of CastContext.

Does anyone helps anyidea?