# Android : Multiple activities with ChromeCast sender

Tags: android, android-activity, chromecast

I followed [this tutorial from google](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender) to create an app to `dialog` with chrome cast.
I succeed in this way but with a single `Activity`. I can't launch another `activity` and `dialog` with the launched receiver in the first one. Some issues from other people problems was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722961/chromecast-with-multiple-activity) but I didn't manage to use it. Could anyone help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: You have to state your issue more clearly, state what you have done and why the suggestion in the other post didn't work for you; with the info you currently have here, we cannot really provide any useful help.If you are not comfortable with using the Cast SDK directly, you may want to use some wrapper libraries like CastCompanionLibrary that should make interaction with the cast SDK easier. If you decide to do so, take a look at the CastVideos-android which uses that library. Both of these can be found at http://github.com/googlecast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the bad way I asked it. But I solved my issue using [this library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) and examples which are given with. Thanks for your replies !